# How do I create an average for a temperature data set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, split

I am writing a program which takes a set of data and then averages it. This data set is the average temperature at Laguardia Airport for every month which corresponds with a temperature.

Here is an example one data point:

```
    2009-07,23.6
```

Which is year-month, temp.

I have 163 data points. All of the data points are in a .txt file, each on a new line.

I made the data into an array and split it. For some reason, my program says my average is 0 every time I try to run it

Here is my code:

```
data = File.open("avg_temp.txt", "r+")

contents = data.read

contents = contents.split("\r\n")

contents.collect! do |x|
        x.split(',')
end


sum = 0

data.each do |x|

sum = sum  + x[1].to_f

end

avg = sum / contents.length

puts avg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign `avg = sum/contents.length` outside the loop after the end.  Variables defined within a loop have a scope limited to that loop. Also you are looping over `data`, should be `content`

```
contents.each do |x|

    puts x[1] # to check if the right value is being evaluated
    sum = sum  + x[1].to_f     

end

avg = sum/contents.length
```

Comment: you have `temp[1]` in the loop but it is not defined anywhere..should it be `x[1]`?

Comment: I did that but is still says 0

Comment: updated the answer , it will print values within the loop to the console so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your `avg` is not the top level local variable. Thus you can't access it from the top level. `avg` is scoped to the block only. You can do below :-

```
avg = 0

data.each do |x|
  sum = sum  + temp[1].to_f
  avg = sum / contents.length
end

puts avg
```

Comment: This recalculates `avg` for no real purpose inside the loop, as a kind of unused "running average". For the OP, it only *needs* calculating when the sum is complete.

Comment: @NeilSlater You are right! I just tried to show to remove the error what he could do..

Comment: I switch the avg = sum / contents.length to be outside the loop. It fixes the error but now it says my avg is 0.???

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = 0
data.each do |x|
    sum = sum  + temp[1].to_f
    avg = sum / contents.length
end
puts avg
```

The `avg` variable is no longer in scope, as it's outside of the each block. To print the avg, simply move it inside of the block like so

```
sum = 0
data.each do |x|
    sum = sum  + temp[1].to_f
    avg = sum / contents.length
    puts avg
end
```

Or move the avg variable outside of the loop (to perform the action once, after your loop has exited)

```
sum = 0
data.each do |x|
    sum = sum  + temp[1].to_f
end

avg = sum / contents.length
puts avg
```

More info at http://rubyflare.com/2009/09/30/variables-scope-and-iterators/

Comment: made the change but is says my average is 0

Comment: Not sure where the variable `temp` is defined, but see this example:

`contents = (1..90).to_a;
sum = 0;`

`contents.each { |x| sum += x } #> 4095` This shows that the sum is now == 4095

`avg = sum/contents.length #> 45` Thus we have the average of 45.

Comment: But the whole point of my program is to not manually add up all the temperatures. I have hundreds of data points

Comment: I did not manually add up these numbers - I only created the `contents` variable to show you how to do this in your code, and that the method above works. Of course, if your `temp[1].to_f` results in a nil or 0 value, then the sum will never increment.

Comment: Where do I put the method in my program?

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this more simply:

```
lines = 0
sum = 0

File.foreach("avg_temp.txt") do |data|
  sum += data.split(',').last.to_f
  lines = $.
end

puts 'Average: %f over %d datapoints' % [sum / lines.to_i, lines]
# >> Average: 23.375000 over 4 datapoints
```

Which outputs:

```
Average: 23.375000 over 4 datapoints
```

Starting with "avg_temp.txt" looking like:

```
2009-07,23.6
2009-08,23.7
2009-09,23.6
2009-10,22.6
```

To 'splain it:

- `$.` is the current line number. Each time through the loop it reassigns the last read line-number to `lines` so we know how many to divide by.
- `foreach` reads line-by-line, so there's no need to split the file. That also explains why I use `$.` to keep track of the number of elements. It also means this could read a file containing millions or billions of values without a problem, where `read` would go to its knees.